# rails4 ajax returning the text inside my .js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to set up an ajax dropdown that will replace the contents of two charts/graphs based on the dropdown. The problem is that instead of just replacing that partial, it actually ends up rendering exactly what is in my js.erb file.

In my View I have:

```
<h3 class="att">Index Markets
    <%= form_tag(chart_path(:format=>:js), {:method=>"GET", :remote=> true})  do %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :id, params[:id]%>
            <%= select_tag(:sector, options_for_select([['All Sectors',3], ['Equities',4], ['Fixed Income',5], ['Currencies',6], ['Commodities',7]]),
            onchange: 'this.form.submit()')%>

    <% end %>
</h3>

<div id="chart_partial">
        <%= render partial: "chart", locals: {risk:@mkt_risk, ret: @mkt_ret}%>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
  def update_chart
    num = params[:sector].to_i
    all = ['SP','NQ','DJ','NK','SX','DX','SE','TU','FV','TY','US','BS','BM','BL','LG','EC','JY','BP','AD','CD','SF','CL','NG','GC','SI','HG','PL','C','W','S','LH','LC']
    mkt_arr = [[],[],[],all,all[1..6],all[7..14],all[15..20],all[21..-1]]
    mkts=mkt_arr[num]
    data = Attribution.where(:index_id=>params[:id],:type=>num)
    risk = data.pluck(:risk).first
    ret = data.pluck(:return).first
    @mkt_risk = mkts.zip(risk)
    @mkt_ret = mkts.zip(ret)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js{
        }
    end
  end
```

Then in update_chart.js.erb I have:

```
 $("#chart_partial").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'chart', locals: {risk:@mkt_risk, ret: @mkt_ret} ) %>");
```

My partial _chart.html.erb is:

```
<div class="chart2">
    <%= pie_chart risk, :library=>{:is3D => true,:title=>'Realized Volatility'} %>
</div>
<div class="chart3">
    <%= column_chart ret, :library=>{:title=>'Annualized Returns'}%>
</div>
```

My output looks is just the contents of the js file with the chart partial calculated on a white background in plain text.

$("#chart_partial").html("\n    \n  Loading...\n</div>\n\n  new Chartkick.PieChart(\"chart-1\", [[\"TU\",0.105915369876919],[\"FV\",0.109578737820998],[\"TY\",0.113233218167653],[\"US\",0.110792736994865],[\"BS\",0.128625046761138],[\"BM\",0.132789248798581],[\"BL\",0.137079687448451],[\"LG\",0.161985954131393]], {\"library\":{\"is3D\":true,\"title\":\"Realized Volatility\"}});\n</script>\n\n</div>\n\n  \n  Loading...\n</div>\n\n  new Chartkick.ColumnChart(\"chart-2\", [[\"TU\",0.00197521267400713],[\"FV\",0.00289326291991543],[\"TY\",0.00364311932366435],[\"US\",0.00329300336431948],[\"BS\",0.00284554054267638],[\"BM\",0.00533162857564418],[\"BL\",0.0058341286792607],[\"LG\",0.00432347733360738]], {\"library\":{\"title\":\"Annualized Returns\"}});\n</script>\n\n</div>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the

```
 onchange: 'this.form.submit()')%>
```

portion of the code was causing the request to not be sent as AJAX even with the remote true.

Once I changed it to this it worked:

```
onchange: "$(this).parent('form').submit();")%>
```

I have no idea why though, so if someone can explain that would be greatly appreciated